# YII - Load all parent records where all has_many records accepts a condition

Tags: php, yii

In the below code this will load all author with one of its posts that has post.title = 'search'

```
// query criteria
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
// with Post model
$criteria->with = array('posts');
// compare title
$criteria->compare('posts.title', $searchWord, true);
// find all authors
$authors = Author::model()->findAll($criteria);
// show all authors and his/her posts
foreach($authors as $author)
{
    echo "Author = " . $author->name . "\n";
    foreach($author->posts as $post)
    {
        echo "Post = " . $post->title . "\n";
    }
}
```

But what I need is only load those authors whose all posts accepts the condition. I am using pagination here so I would like to do it one find statement.

I browsed a lot on this but what  can find is eager loading and lazy loading of HAS_MANY records but what I need is different.

Can anyone help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide authors with all posts satisfying the condition

```
// query criteria
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
// with Post model
$criteria->with = array('posts');
// compare title
$criteria->compare('posts.title', $searchWord, true);

$criteria->select = ['*',new CDbExpression('(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts WHERE author_id = t.id) AS all_posts'),new CDbExpression('COUNT(posts.id) AS post_count')];

$criteria->group = 't.id';

$criteria->distinct = true;

$criteria->having = 'all_posts = post_count';

// find all authors
$authors = Author::model()->findAll($criteria);
// show all authors and his/her posts
foreach($authors as $author)
{
    echo "Author = " . $author->name . "\n";
    foreach($author->posts as $post)
    {
        echo "Post = " . $post->title . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about searching by posts and not by authors?

```
// query criteria
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
// with author model
$criteria->rightJoin('author', 'author.id=post.author_id')
// compare title
$criteria->compare('title', $searchWord, true);

//optional: group by author
$criteria->group = 'author.id';

// find all posts
$posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);

// show all post with theirs author
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    echo "Post = " . $post->title . "\n";
    echo "Author = " . $post->author->name .  "\n";
}
```

Comment: this does not filter out the author who has any post not matching the criteria. Because the question seems to be about :  *authors whose all posts accepts the condition*

Answer (score -1):

The solution requires you to query for authors with required post criteria and then check if those authors do not have any the post not satisfying the criteria.

In simple sql, that would mean something like this

```
select * from author where id in (select author from post where post.title like '%word%') and id not in (select author from post where postcriteria not like '%word%')
```

Implementing this in Yii requires [db query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)  , example query would be

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('*')
->from('author') 
->where('id in (select author from post where post.title like %:word%) 
 and id not in (select author from post where post.title not like %:word%)', array(':word'=>$word))
->queryRow();
```

Comment: I am new to Yii. I would like post my finding here please let me know which one is the best answer.